# Careless mistake in my htaccess rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing an .htaccess rule as

```
RewriteRule ^questions\/interview\/list\/(.+)$ questions\/interview\/list\/index.php?col1=$1
```

So, when I am calling url `questions/interview/list/testme` it's redirecting to `index.php`.

Issue is when i am printing `$col1` its showing index.php instead of testme. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: At best you get an internal error. You don't have to escape the `/` in rewriterules and the second argument is a string and doesn't require any escaping at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the rewrite engine loops, try adding some conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^questions/interview/list/(.+)$ questions/interview/list/index.php?col1=$1 [L]
```

or even:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^questions/interview/list/(.+)$ questions/interview/list/index.php?col1=$1 [L]
```

When the rewrite engine loops, the `(.+)` part of your regex ends up matching `index.php`, and thus `col1=` turns into `index.php`.

Comment: thanx, it work... will choose ur answer as best ans in 10 min